# How to scale "message read by" and "is writing..." chat features?

Tags: node.js, chat, scale, pusher

I've seen a lot of questions about how to `scale chats`, but none of them seem to address the problem of those two features which can dramatically increase http requests.

**Example:**

When `n` personne are chatting, everyone someone sends a message, it's 1 HTTP request, and `(n-1)` messages that are pushed back.

Now everytime someone "reads" the message (trigger when `$(input).on('focus')` for example), it's `(n-1)` times new http requests, and `(n-1)²` messages that are pushed back.

And everytime someone signals to other people he started writing, it's one new http request followed by `n-1` websocket messages.

But since for each message there is a chance that he doesnt send anything at all (but erase his message and stop writting instead), we can assume that it's going to be at least `(n-1)*k`

`k>1` represents a persons tendancy to write/erase his writings before sending them

Consider 4 persons chating, and one of them send one message to the chat.

**Case one** - No feature             | `1 http` request, `3 websocket` messages

**Case two** - "Message read feature" *only* | `4 http` requests, `12 websocket` messages

**Case three** "*is writting...* feature *only*, `k=1` | `2 http` requests, `6 websocket` messages

Summing up : `1 http / 3 ws`  vs `6 http / 18 ws`  for **one message only** and **assuming k=1**

I'm using `node.js` & `pusher` in my app, and before I start implementing these two, I wanna make sure my costs won't litteraly explode lol. Any clue on how Facebook did that by the way, with billions of messages ? (im not sure cost is a problem for them though)

Is there a *smart* way to implement and scale these 2 features, with a websocket provider such a `Pusher` for example ?

I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you describe the two features you're asking about?  What do they do?  And, why do you think they would be a scale problem?

Comment: How does it ‘exponentially’ increase HTTP requests? You might get a linear factor more requests, but you can treat it as a message nearly like any other.

Comment: It's not actually exponential growth, but still it's huge. I added examples, let me know if its clearer and if you agree with my maths lol

Comment: None has a clue? That can't be !

Comment: Why not considering using websockets to send the data to the server as well? Then you can do it with only one socket open per person chatting. Then internally, serverside, you need some broadcast events for these sockets, for instance "room3:user1:isTyping=true". which will be broadcast to all the sockets subscribing to the "room3" channel, or similar. Subscriptions can be managed serverside, instead of one per socket. For this you can use for instance redis. Have a look here http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/